# Api-maps на всех страницах

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

У меня есть главная страница, на которой рендеряться другие

```
</div>
    <div id="page">
    <% if controller_name != 'error' %>
      <div class="error_report modals"></div>
    <% end %>
        <div id="header">
            <%= render @p::Header %>
        </div><!--header-->
        <div id="bar">
            <%= render @p::Bar %>
        </div><!--bar-->
        <div id="wrapper" class="container">
            <div id="top">
                <div class="rows">
                    <div class="left">
                        <div class="slider slider1">
                          <%= render @p::Slider %>
                        </div> и т.д.
```

В header подключаю JS-ку

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Roboto:300,400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'market/desktop/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7-8.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'market/desktop/application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
</head>
```

Как сделать так,чтобы js-ка api-maps подключалась только на определенной странице,а не на всех?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил так

```
<% if controller_name == 'company' %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?
     lang=ru_RU"></script>
<% end %>
```